# xcode app submission error: "no eligible software found, make sure this software is owned by your developer organization"

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm getting the stated error when trying to upload an app submission to itunes connect on an organization I am a member of, but who's itunes connect username is different than my my apple developer ID.

The problem is I have a single Apple Developer ID I use for all my IOS development across multiple organizations.  my.name@gmail.com  That id has been added to multiple organizations in the IOS Member Center.  On Itunes Connect however, it does not let you add an existing Apple ID (or existing Itunes Connect user on a different organization) as a new user to an organization.

So if I'm a member of 3 organizations, each one uses a different Itunes Connect email, usually the email for that org, not my main gmail Apple ID.

When trying to upload using XCode, I get this error since they don't match.  How can I work around this?  I fixed it for one organization only by using my co-worker's ID which matched for his appleID+itunes user.  However I'd like to be able to do it on my own.

I tried adding individual org emails as xcode emails, however none of them are Apple Developer accounts, and Xcode refuses to use them.

How can I upload my app to a new org I'm a member of on Itunes connect??

**EDIT**

I tried using the Application Loader tool from Xcode menu, and I get a different kind of error shown below.  I tried with App Store Build and Ad Hoc build.  This is a development build only at this point which I hope to use for internal testing via Itunes Connect Testflight, so we're not using Release/AppStore provisioning profiles yet, nor have we even created them yet.

**EDIT 2**

Apple docs say:

*"A single Apple ID can be associated with multiple Member Center teams. Using the same Apple ID, you can enroll as an individual and join other teams. However, you can only be associated with a single iTunes Connect team. Consequently, developers should create another Apple ID for different individual or company accounts that they want to manage separately in iTunes Connect."*

This is true for itunes connect.  But how does one then submit builds to these other itunes connect accounts, from xcode?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I was able to sort this out and thought I'd share for others looking for answers.  Because I have a single apple developer id and multiple iTunes Connect ids, that is the core of the problem. Xcode would not let me put and use a non-developer account id into the user preferences.  The solution was to use the Application Loader tool.

An Overview of necessary steps, which I use for every deployment now:

- Make sure your Release build is using a Distribution provisioning profile and not just a development one.  Don't use "Automatic" either, even if it sometimes works.  I use an App Store profile, even for test flight releases via ITC.  Create the provisioning profile on apple's ios center manually, call it something obvious like "[APP_NAME] App Store Distribution".  Then in the Xcode build settings, set the release profile to this name.  Secondly, make sure the Code Signing developer is the one on this profile, it doesn't always toggle default to that.
- Archive your app as usual to generate the build.
- Do not "submit" app from organizer, instead do an export, export to file.
- When prompted, choose "App Store Submission" instead of "Ad hoc", otherwise it will fail.
- In Xcode open Xcode->Open Developer Tool->Application Loader
- From here you can add/select any of your itunes connect users independent of Xcode.
- Choose "deliver your app" to submit, and choose the exported build file.

This should get the upload to itunes connect.  If you are using TestFlight in ITC and it is setup, this will result in a new TestFlight push.

When creating a new app for each organization I work with, I always setup the new Distribution profile immediately, don't start using "Automatic" or let Xcode "Fix it...", as these may work once, but will likely cause issues or failed releases later.  Always name your profiles to include the app name, distribution and App Store, as once you start doing this a lot it is easy to confuse them if you're just naming them non descriptively like "MyApp's profile".

Comment: In my case the issue was that I had two Apple IDs - one was associated with a Developer Program, and the other was associated with iTunesConnect. Have to use the iTunesConnect account to submit the app. Duh! Application Loader makes it easier to switch accounts than Xcode.

Comment: Excellent, this worked for me as well since I had multiple id's from the same mock email addresses.

Comment: I keep getting a request timed out error. I followed the steps exactly as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

"No eligible software" suggests that either the appID doesn't exist or it exists on the wrong developer account (perhaps Xcode auto created).

Check the team you're using normally (if it's wrong, XC might have done something useful but in the wrong account). Start with Xcode Preferences > Accounts then details of the preferred and current teams in question. After that, check in the devcenter (making sure you're logged in as the team you're trying to submit under) - check your appIDs and see if the app you're expecting to see there actually is.

Also make sure the iTunes Connect account you're using to upload has the "technical" role (per https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/UsingiTunesConnect/UsingiTunesConnect.html)

Comment: I am an Admin on itunes connect, which seems to encompass all previous roles including Technical; is that correct?

Comment: Yes, Admin includes technical, but (just checking) for which team? You mention that you're a member of three different organizations -- that implies three teams. Are you admin of the account under which you're trying to submit and getting these errors?

Comment: yeah, i'm an admin on the unsubmittable itunes account.  Note, the itunes account email is not the same as my apple developer id-- i think that is the issue.

Comment: There're enough voodoo variables that go into this stuff that I don't have further suggestions in the general case. It'll probably take a specific, detailed walkthrough to identify the mismatch. Good luck with it!

Comment: I've never found a solution for this. I am a technical user, I have all the privileges, access I need and yet it will not allow me to submit an app. 

My "solution" is that I use XCode 5.x.x just for submissions (archives built with 6 and available) and it works. 

Sad that after all these years Apple still unable to make this process anything but a PITA.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was I didn't realized that "Application Loader" has a login! 
So I just select Window menu / Sign In as.. And enter the same developer account I used to create the "certificate and provision files", that I used to compile the app.

Answer (score 0):

Please match the bundle Id from itunesConnect & Xcode.

I was getting same error & solved with bundleID.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Application Loader user account to application's signed user account.